# appendChild with SVG brings a HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3) in IE9.0

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-9

The following code works fine in chrome and Firefox, but breaks in IE 9.0

```
//select div where svg is to be inserted
var selSVG = document.getElementById('SVGMap');
//clear any SVG
while (selSVG.hasChildNodes()) {
selSVG.removeChild(selSVG.lastChild);
}
//add the new svg
selSVG.appendChild(loadXML("roomlayouts/"+SelectedRoomAddress));
```

with loadXML(...) returning an svg document from another folder and with the error on the last line of DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3) line 300 character 2

Any ideas why it's not working in IE 9.0?

The implementation is here: http://chocolatezombies.com/classroom/classroom.html

Comment: What, exactly, is being returned by `loadXML`?

Comment: it returns a full SVG document for xample: http://chocolatezombies.com/classroom/roomlayouts/S110.svg

Comment: @999 I should have said it returns the documentelement of the SVG file.  sorry, just took a harder look at my code.  function copied below

function loadXML(url)
   {
 var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
 //stops the annoying caching!
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
 //as it says above
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 return xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [import](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#Core-Document-importNode) the element from the loaded document into the document of selSVG before you may append it. Per the specs, you would do:

```
var room = loadXML(...);
if (room.nodeType==9){         // You can't import entire documents, so
  room = room.documentElement; // get the root node of the document
}
room = selSVG.ownerDocument.importNode( room );
selSVG.appendChild( room );
```

However, IE9 does not properly implement `importNode`. I have provided a workaround method for this as part of my answer to this question: [How do I dynamically insert an SVG image into HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981100/how-do-i-dynamically-insert-an-svg-image-into-html/7986519#7986519)

Comment: hi @Phrogz,  I'm struggling to get this working.  I took a look at your example code attached and it keeps bringing up the following error in IE9.0:  `Unable to get value of the property 'namespaceURI': object is null or undefined` on the following line `var clone = doc.createElementNS(node.namespaceURI,node.nodeName);`  

to clarify: loadXML(...) is returning the following: `xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;`

Comment: To clarify further, the SVG I am loading is created in inkscape and has all the appropriate namespace information namely: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Comment: @pluke Make a test case showing this problem and host it online if you want further help; otherwise, you'll need to learn to debug. (Hint: that error means that the value of `node` is null. You need to figure out why.)

Comment: Hi @Phrogz, I have found the issue.  The SVGs that inkscape output have more namespace information than your `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Such as:
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"'
Your code
`if (a.nodeName=="xmlns") continue;
 clone.setAttributeNS(a.namespaceURI,a.nodeName,a.nodeValue);`
can't handle subsets of the xmlns.  Sorry about the slow response, I have limited access to a Win7 machine.  Try loading this: http://chocolatezombies.com/classroom/roomlayouts/S110.svg with your example

Comment: @pluke Ah, right you are. I've fixed my examples to use `if (/^xmlns\b/.test(a.nodeName)) continue;` instead and confirmed that your S110.svg file is able to be loaded in IE9 with that change. Thanks for the report.

Comment: The `cloneToDoc` function described in @Phrogz's linked answer solves the problem with IE9 (and saves my life :). With Chrome (38 - as the time of writing this), everything works also without `importNode`. E.g.: `var room = loadXML(...); selSVG.appendChild(room.documentElement)`. BTW, the SVG I'm using is also created with Inkscape.